# NPE при записи файла. Разница между ObjectOutputStream и OutputStreamWriter

Tags: java, android

Этот конструктор выполняется при создании экземпляра класса.

```
public RecordAdapter(Context context) {

    mContext = context;
    try {
        String str = "Привет";
        OutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput("memoria", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(str);
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Произошла ошибка записи", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

}
```

Я думаю мне не понадобится прикладывать лог, т.к. здесь наверняка какая-то грубая ошибка.

Что изменится если я вместо того ,что в коде напишу это : os.writeObject(str.getBytes());

Я так понимаю OutputStreamWriter , это частный случай ObjectOutputStream. Случай когда мне нужно записать данные в текстовом формате. Если использовать ObjectOutputStream, то в файл запишется массив байт. Я запутался отличия бинарный файл от текстового, вроде одно и тоже, а вроде и нет. Если одно и то же, то почему два разных метода ?

Comment: Где именно возникает NPE? Какой объект не существует?

Comment: Написано, что невозможно создать экземпляр активности и выдает NPE.  Ругается на Toast.. Если убрать эту строку , то NPE нет. Ну и этот код всегда попадает в Catch{}. Вместо тост я использовал лог и это код в логе выполняется раз десять. Он никак не может создать файл. Эта строка не может выполниться никак OutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput("memoria", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: Ошибку нашел . Я в том классе где создаю экземпляр написал RecordAdapter mRecordAdapter = new RecordAdapter(this) , а в onCreate() не проинициализировал. Я не совсем понимаю в чем разница. Наверно если в поле класса написать RecordAdapter mRecordAdapter = new RecordAdapter(this)  никаких this не передастся , так как их пока еще нет , так? или что то не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ObjectOutputStream** предназначен для сериализации объектов в поток.

**OutputStreamWriter** предназначен для сохранения текстовых данных в поток. Он умеет правильно работать с кодировками.

Если вы запишите строку в **OutputStreamWriter**, то он преобразует ее в набор байт в соответствии с установленной кодировкой.

Если вы запишите в **ObjectOutputStream** массив байт (`os.writeObject(str.getBytes())`), то никакой обработки кодировки не будет. Более того вы потеряет информацию о том, что это была строка и длинна массива тоже потеряется.

Comment: Т.е. в запись os.writeObject(str.getBytes()) в ObjectOutputStream , даст тоже самое , что и строка записанная  в ObjectOutputStream?

Comment: С NPE, разобрался. Если писать str.getBytes() , то этот  файл больше не читается в строку. В Integer тоже не прочитался. Я для записи использовал ObjectOutputStream и записанное прочиталось в строку без изменений. Ну как я понял сериализация как раз учитывает, то что это строка и записывает данные о кодировке. (Я прав?) А если превратить в набор байт и записать, тот как прочесть это?

Comment: сериализация кодировку не учитывает, так как это бинарный формат. там данные будут во внутренней кодировке. если записать набор байт, то и читать надо набор байт и потом его можно будет превратить в строку.